# Gender voice recognition in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, voice-recognition

I am creating an application in which I want to recognise the gender of the voice whether it is male or female. I googled it but didn't find any proper solution so i just want to know whether it is possible or not? I have got [lium](http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/welcome) but don't know how to use. Any help would be appreciable...

Answer (score 2):

For Android you have to implement this algorithm yourself.

For gender voice detection you can train a simple GMM detector. You can extract features with http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid and then just apply a GMM detector on top to classify between classes.

You can read the following publication on topic:

http://www.dfki.de/web/research/publications/renameFileForDownload?filename=IS100346.pdf&file_id=uploads_877

In Matlab the implementation is available and explained here here: http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/developing-an-isolated-word-recognition-system-in-matlab.html
It is used to recognize words but the same way you can recognize gender - just train GMM for males and another one for females.

Comment: Can you please elaborate something about gmm detector?

Comment: Sure, let me know what are you interested in. I've added matlab code link.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it in android?

Comment: Yes, you can implement that on Android.

Comment: How to implement in android because i didn't find any proper solution.....